# Tableau dashboard to easily show data from different quarters

Tags: tableau

I have 2 data sources linked that are the same format but from 2 different quarters. My boss wants to have 1 dashboard with an option to flip between the 2 quarters data so the graphs and things change when he changes which quarter he’s viewing. As of right now, my best is having a dashboard for each of the quarters

Comment: Is this possible for you to share a screenshot of your current visualization and pointing out your desired change in it?

Comment: Because the information is confidential, I can't really share it.  My goal is to have an easy way for my boss to change one setting to see the data on the dashboard for a different date range.  I relate it to what we can do with a Google Data Studio dashboard where the dashboard has a variety of components/widgets & we can change the date range in the upper right corner & the dashboard components refresh.  Is something like that possible in Tableau.

Comment: As I am thinking about this, I am thinking that perhaps I need to have one data set with all the data & then have filter boxes that allow him to choose date ranges.  I have no idea how to do that yet, but in theory that is what I am thinking needs to happen.  Does that sound right?

Comment: I think I know what to do now.  Need a data set with all data I am want to work with & add filter criteria options.

Comment: There you go! Share your answer if you got what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If the two sources are truly the same format, add a column to each denoting the quarter and then union them instead of loading them separately. All that will be left is to add a dashboard action on that new column to toggle between the two quarters.

Comment: Thanks - trying that now